# Use JavaScript to change the content of a JQuery WYSIWYG editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwysiwyg

I want to put the value in textarea using the jquery. I'm using the following code. It is not working.

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.wysiwyg.css" type="text/css" />
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.wysiwyg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function wedit(topic){
    $("#wysiwyg").html(topic);  
    alert(id+topic+instructor+date+video);
   }
 </script>
 <form name="theform" action="" method="post">
 <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" width="680px">
 <tr><td width="150">Topic:</td><td><span id="wtopic">
  <textarea name="wysiwyg" id="wysiwyg" ></textarea></span></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" 
  title="Save" /></td>  </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
```

It is working in case of text but in case of textarea it is showing empty value.
please let me know how can I put the text into the textarea through jquery or javascript??

Comment: Please try reducing your code to the simplest sample that will reproduce your problem. That's too much code for us to wade through for such a simple problem.

Comment: Down bump purely due to this answer is easily found with 15 seconds of research.  You clearly have the JS file which in it's raw unminified form has every answer you could possibly want in less than 300 lines of code.  Add to that the wiki page which is linked multiple places with the JQuery.WYSIWYG files also explains this concept.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/wiki/Introduction

First off, the wiki has  about everything you need.  Not sure what your question is past that buuuuuuuuuuuuut....

**Getting content**
You can get the textarea content just using .val() method from jquery

```
$('#wysiwyg').val();
```

**Content manipulation**
If you want to manipulate the jwysiwyg textarea content you can use the next methods

Insert an image
Insert an image on text indicator

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('insertImage', 'http://domain.com/image.png');
```

**Insert a link**
Insert a link over selected text

```
$('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg('createLink', 'http://google.com/');
```

If this doesn't answer your questions, I know I have a prototype spike laying around here somewhere with jquery.wysiwyg.js in it.

**EDIT** Going to be pre-emptive here but...  Keep in mind jwysiwyg after init no longer functions like a raw text box, if you want to inject HTML you must do so before you .wysiwyg(...) init call.  Please ignore the MVC @Url.Content(...) methods.  You should be able to get what you need from below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.css")" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jwysiwyg/jquery.wysiwyg.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jwysiwyg/controls/wysiwyg.link.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Content/jwysiwyg/controls/wysiwyg.table.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
            initialContent: "**INITIAL CONTENT HERE IF YOU WANT TO INJECT SOMETHING AT INIT TIME**",
            css: "@Url.Content("~/Content/comments.css")?upd=00000002",
            controls: {
                bold: { visible: true },
                italic: { visible: true },
                underline: { visible: true },
                strikeThrough: { visible: true },

                insertImage: { visible: false },

                justifyLeft: { visible: true },
                justifyCenter: { visible: true },
                justifyRight: { visible: true },
                justifyFull: { visible: true },

                indent: { visible: true },
                outdent: { visible: true },

                subscript: { visible: true },
                superscript: { visible: true },

                undo: { visible: true },
                redo: { visible: true },

                insertOrderedList: { visible: true },
                insertUnorderedList: { visible: true },
                insertHorizontalRule: { visible: true },
                cut: { visible: true },
                copy: { visible: true },
                paste: { visible: true },
                html: { visible: false },
                increaseFontSize: { visible: true },
                decreaseFontSize: { visible: true },

                h1: { visible: false },
                h2: { visible: false },
                h3: { visible: false },
                exam_html: { visible: false }
            },
            events: {
                click: function (event) {

                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<textarea rows="10" cols="100" id="wysiwyg" name="@Model.FormName">
    <!-- HTML GOES HERE -->
</textarea>
```

**EDIT #2**

Keeping in mind like all JQuery UI controls after you init the control you now have to operate through the API exposed to you by the control itself.  In this case it is the $("#YourTextArea").wysiwyg("method","arguments");

A complete list of actions you can take on the JQuery.WYSIWYG control are easily found in the JS file matching the toolbar names but in case you wanted them (I'm not going through and cleaning up the list, sorry for the mess but you'll have to read the first generation of the indents to gather the method names)

```
bold: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["b", "strong"],
            css: {
                fontWeight: "bold"
            },
            tooltip: "Bold",
            hotkey: { "ctrl": 1, "key": 66 }
        },

        copy: {
            groupIndex: 8,
            visible: false,
            tooltip: "Copy"
        },

        createLink: {
            groupIndex: 6,
            visible: true,
            exec: function () {
                var self = this;
                if ($.wysiwyg.controls && $.wysiwyg.controls.link) {
                    $.wysiwyg.controls.link.init(this);
                } else if ($.wysiwyg.autoload) {
                    $.wysiwyg.autoload.control("wysiwyg.link.js", function () {
                        self.controls.createLink.exec.apply(self);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("$.wysiwyg.controls.link not defined. You need to include wysiwyg.link.js file");
                }
            },
            tags: ["a"],
            tooltip: "Create link"
        },

        unLink: {
            groupIndex: 6,
            visible: true,
            exec: function () {
                this.editorDoc.execCommand("unlink", false, null);
            },
            tooltip: "Remove link"
        },

        cut: {
            groupIndex: 8,
            visible: false,
            tooltip: "Cut"
        },

        decreaseFontSize: {
            groupIndex: 9,
            visible: false,
            tags: ["small"],
            tooltip: "Decrease font size",
            exec: function () {
                this.decreaseFontSize();
            }
        },

        h1: {
            groupIndex: 7,
            visible: true,
            className: "h1",
            command: ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "FormatBlock" : "heading",
            "arguments": ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "<h1>" : "h1",
            tags: ["h1"],
            tooltip: "Header 1"
        },

        h2: {
            groupIndex: 7,
            visible: true,
            className: "h2",
            command: ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "FormatBlock" : "heading",
            "arguments": ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "<h2>" : "h2",
            tags: ["h2"],
            tooltip: "Header 2"
        },

        h3: {
            groupIndex: 7,
            visible: true,
            className: "h3",
            command: ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "FormatBlock" : "heading",
            "arguments": ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "<h3>" : "h3",
            tags: ["h3"],
            tooltip: "Header 3"
        },

        highlight: {
            tooltip: "Highlight",
            className: "highlight",
            groupIndex: 1,
            visible: false,
            css: {
                backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 255, 102)"
            },
            exec: function () {
                var command, node, selection, args;

                if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) {
                    command = "backcolor";
                } else {
                    command = "hilitecolor";
                }

                if ($.browser.msie) {
                    node = this.getInternalRange().parentElement();
                } else {
                    selection = this.getInternalSelection();
                    node = selection.extentNode || selection.focusNode;

                    while (node.style === undefined) {
                        node = node.parentNode;
                        if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === "body") {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (node.style.backgroundColor === "rgb(255, 255, 102)" ||
                        node.style.backgroundColor === "#ffff66") {
                    args = "#ffffff";
                } else {
                    args = "#ffff66";
                }

                this.editorDoc.execCommand(command, false, args);
            }
        },

        html: {
            groupIndex: 10,
            visible: false,
            exec: function () {
                var elementHeight;

                if (this.options.resizeOptions && $.fn.resizable) {
                    elementHeight = this.element.height();
                }

                if (this.viewHTML) { //textarea is shown
                    this.setContent(this.original.value);

                    $(this.original).hide();
                    this.editor.show();

                    if (this.options.resizeOptions && $.fn.resizable) {
                        // if element.height still the same after frame was shown
                        if (elementHeight === this.element.height()) {
                            this.element.height(elementHeight + this.editor.height());
                        }

                        this.element.resizable($.extend(true, {
                            alsoResize: this.editor
                        }, this.options.resizeOptions));
                    }

                    this.ui.toolbar.find("li").each(function () {
                        var li = $(this);

                        if (li.hasClass("html")) {
                            li.removeClass("active");
                        } else {
                            li.removeClass('disabled');
                        }
                    });
                } else { //wysiwyg is shown
                    this.saveContent();

                    $(this.original).css({
                        width: this.element.outerWidth() - 6,
                        height: this.element.height() - this.ui.toolbar.height() - 6,
                        resize: "none"
                    }).show();
                    this.editor.hide();

                    if (this.options.resizeOptions && $.fn.resizable) {
                        // if element.height still the same after frame was hidden
                        if (elementHeight === this.element.height()) {
                            this.element.height(this.ui.toolbar.height());
                        }

                        this.element.resizable("destroy");
                    }

                    this.ui.toolbar.find("li").each(function () {
                        var li = $(this);

                        if (li.hasClass("html")) {
                            li.addClass("active");
                        } else {
                            if (false === li.hasClass("fullscreen")) {
                                li.removeClass("active").addClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                this.viewHTML = !(this.viewHTML);
            },
            tooltip: "View source code"
        },

        increaseFontSize: {
            groupIndex: 9,
            visible: false,
            tags: ["big"],
            tooltip: "Increase font size",
            exec: function () {
                this.increaseFontSize();
            }
        },

        indent: {
            groupIndex: 2,
            visible: true,
            tooltip: "Indent"
        },

        insertHorizontalRule: {
            groupIndex: 6,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["hr"],
            tooltip: "Insert Horizontal Rule"
        },

        insertImage: {
            groupIndex: 6,
            visible: true,
            exec: function () {
                var self = this;

                if ($.wysiwyg.controls && $.wysiwyg.controls.image) {
                    $.wysiwyg.controls.image.init(this);
                } else if ($.wysiwyg.autoload) {
                    $.wysiwyg.autoload.control("wysiwyg.image.js", function () {
                        self.controls.insertImage.exec.apply(self);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("$.wysiwyg.controls.image not defined. You need to include wysiwyg.image.js file");
                }
            },
            tags: ["img"],
            tooltip: "Insert image"
        },

        insertOrderedList: {
            groupIndex: 5,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["ol"],
            tooltip: "Insert Ordered List"
        },

        insertTable: {
            groupIndex: 6,
            visible: true,
            exec: function () {
                var self = this;

                if ($.wysiwyg.controls && $.wysiwyg.controls.table) {
                    $.wysiwyg.controls.table(this);
                } else if ($.wysiwyg.autoload) {
                    $.wysiwyg.autoload.control("wysiwyg.table.js", function () {
                        self.controls.insertTable.exec.apply(self);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.error("$.wysiwyg.controls.table not defined. You need to include wysiwyg.table.js file");
                }
            },
            tags: ["table"],
            tooltip: "Insert table"
        },

        insertUnorderedList: {
            groupIndex: 5,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["ul"],
            tooltip: "Insert Unordered List"
        },

        italic: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["i", "em"],
            css: {
                fontStyle: "italic"
            },
            tooltip: "Italic",
            hotkey: { "ctrl": 1, "key": 73 }
        },

        justifyCenter: {
            groupIndex: 1,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["center"],
            css: {
                textAlign: "center"
            },
            tooltip: "Justify Center"
        },

        justifyFull: {
            groupIndex: 1,
            visible: true,
            css: {
                textAlign: "justify"
            },
            tooltip: "Justify Full"
        },

        justifyLeft: {
            visible: true,
            groupIndex: 1,
            css: {
                textAlign: "left"
            },
            tooltip: "Justify Left"
        },

        justifyRight: {
            groupIndex: 1,
            visible: true,
            css: {
                textAlign: "right"
            },
            tooltip: "Justify Right"
        },

        ltr: {
            groupIndex: 10,
            visible: false,
            exec: function () {
                var p = this.dom.getElement("p");

                if (!p) {
                    return false;
                }

                $(p).attr("dir", "ltr");
                return true;
            },
            tooltip: "Left to Right"
        },

        outdent: {
            groupIndex: 2,
            visible: true,
            tooltip: "Outdent"
        },

        paragraph: {
            groupIndex: 7,
            visible: false,
            className: "paragraph",
            command: "FormatBlock",
            "arguments": ($.browser.msie || $.browser.safari) ? "<p>" : "p",
            tags: ["p"],
            tooltip: "Paragraph"
        },

        paste: {
            groupIndex: 8,
            visible: false,
            tooltip: "Paste"
        },

        redo: {
            groupIndex: 4,
            visible: true,
            tooltip: "Redo"
        },

        removeFormat: {
            groupIndex: 10,
            visible: true,
            exec: function () {
                this.removeFormat();
            },
            tooltip: "Remove formatting"
        },

        rtl: {
            groupIndex: 10,
            visible: false,
            exec: function () {
                var p = this.dom.getElement("p");

                if (!p) {
                    return false;
                }

                $(p).attr("dir", "rtl");
                return true;
            },
            tooltip: "Right to Left"
        },

        strikeThrough: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["s", "strike"],
            css: {
                textDecoration: "line-through"
            },
            tooltip: "Strike-through"
        },

        subscript: {
            groupIndex: 3,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["sub"],
            tooltip: "Subscript"
        },

        superscript: {
            groupIndex: 3,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["sup"],
            tooltip: "Superscript"
        },

        underline: {
            groupIndex: 0,
            visible: true,
            tags: ["u"],
            css: {
                textDecoration: "underline"
            },
            tooltip: "Underline",
            hotkey: { "ctrl": 1, "key": 85 }
        },

        undo: {
            groupIndex: 4,
            visible: true,
            tooltip: "Undo"
        },

        code: {
            visible: true,
            groupIndex: 6,
            tooltip: "Code snippet",
            exec: function () {
                var range = this.getInternalRange(),
                    common = $(range.commonAncestorContainer),
                    $nodeName = range.commonAncestorContainer.nodeName.toLowerCase();
                if (common.parent("code").length) {
                    common.unwrap();
                } else {
                    if ($nodeName !== "body") {
                        common.wrap("<code/>");
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        cssWrap: {
            visible: false,
            groupIndex: 6,
            tooltip: "CSS Wrapper",
            exec: function () {
                $.wysiwyg.controls.cssWrap.init(this);
            }
        }
```

Now there's nothing else I can offer ;-)

So in this case you can always do:  $("#YourTextArea").wysiwyg("paragraph","Your Text");  Or any other method from the toolbar.  Warning:  HTML is not what you think it is... so just pointing that out ahead of time.

Comment: I want to put the text into textarea by jqeury.

Comment: See my edit.  You are using a RTE control which makes the text area no longer a raw text area.  You have to use the J.WYSIWYG API to inject content after initialization.  During init there is an "initial content" argument where you can pass information in, but once it is initialized you have to use their API.

Comment: editor is working in this case. I want to insert the text into textarea.

Comment: @user1429132, VulgarBinary is right, once you begin using the plugin, you need to use the methods associated with that plugin to make sure things work correctly.

Comment: $("#YourElement").wysiwyg("paragraph","Whatever");  Look at the JS file... all of the  methods that  are available to you are the same as the toolbar actions.  If you need an unminified version I can link you one.

Comment: Just a note... I added PrettyPrint logic to the "Code" button because I hate what they did there... So if you are wondering why my "code" toolbar button is different that's why.

Answer (score 0):

Though when creating a textarea putting stuff between the `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` tags results in it appearing in the textarea, when reading and writing from/to it in JavaScript, you need to use the `.value="content"` attribute, or in the case of jQuery, `.val("content")`. I see `$("#wysiwyg").html(topic);`, but that should probably be:

```
$("#wysiwyg").val(topic);
```